# Выполнив восходящее преобразование от производного в базовый класс метод не переопределился

Tags: java, наследование

Выполнив восходящее преобразование от производного в базовый класс метод не переопределился? Почему не вызвался метод nasvai() базового класса?

```
class BasicClass {
    void nasvai() { System.out.println("Basic_Nasvai"); }
}

class SubBasic extends BasicClass {
    @Override
    void nasvai() { System.out.println("Nasvai"); }
}

class P231Exc20 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
            SubBasic sb = new SubBasic();
            sb.nasvai();
            BasicClass bc = sb;
            bc.nasvai();
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Nasvai
Nasvai
```

Comment: какое креативное название метода)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А он и не должен был переопределяться. В Java (в отличии от С++ к примеру) все функции делаются виртуальными (virtual) и для поиска функции, которую необходимо вызвать, используется специальная таблица (VMT) которая (упрощённо) каждому объекту при создании ставит в соответствие его тип (по конструктору). И исходя из типа вызывает нужную функцию. При преобразовании типа сохраняется запись в VMT и соответственно происходит вызов функции исходя из типа *созданного* объекта а не связанной с ним переменной.

Answer (score 2):

Если коротко - "потому что полиморфизм".
Так работает наследование в джаве. Более того, определив

```
class BasicClass {
  
  public BasicClass() {
  nasvai();
}

  void nasvai() { System.out.println("Basic_Nasvai"); }
}
```

и создав экземпляр дочернего класса, вы увидите, что будет вызван переопределённый метод. Поэтому не вызыввайте не-static не-final методы в конструкторе во избежание недоразумений.